# Laravel SQL sign in issue

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I've set up an admin log in but upon submitting the form i'm thrown an error. I've tried globally searching `restaurant_users` but i'm unable to find anything.

login controller:

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $this->validate($request, [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:6'
    ]);
    if (Auth::guard('restaurantuser')->attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return redirect()->intended(route('dish.create'));
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->only('email'));

}
```

schema:

```
Schema::create('restaurantuser', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: restaurant_users (SQL: select * from "restaurant_users" where "email" = admin@test.com limit 1)

If any other code is needed let me know and ill provide it.

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to include the most crucial part. Ill edit the code and include it.

Comment: Well... you are working with `restaurantuser` and the error comes from `restaurant_users`...

Comment: Yes and i'm unsure where restaurant_users would be. I've searched through many files and globally search the string but have gotten no results...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `User` model add this:

```
protected $table = 'restaurantuser':
```

The `restaurant_users` comes from Laravel as it assumes that if your model is called `RestaurantUser` that that's the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Hello fellow webApp student.

Would you be kind enough to share how you implemented the administrator role, and the corresponding account approval if you did end up completing it.

Much appreciated,

someone close by...